# mavericks 10.9.5 downloaded but not installing

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

I recently updated mavericks 10.9.5 from 10.9, 
it shows on **Update Installed in last 30 days**, but when I see **About my mac info** it is still showing 10.9

[image]

Again going to app store and clicking update it ask me to restart, to install the update I have restarted many a times but it is still 10.9 please help as I want to install X code 6.1 for learning swift

[image]

Comment: You are showing the Yosemite OS ? There is no longer the 10.9.5 on Apple Store. Did you save a copy of the Mavericks Installer ?

Comment: no I have updated mavericks 10.9.5 specifically as I don't want Yosemite OS for now

Comment: There is no longer Mavericks on Apple Store. You will need a Mavericks Installer to complete your Install.

Comment: but it is showing on my App store account please check the edited screen shot

Comment: OK, try it from here http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macos

Answer (score 1):

@OP: If you have the update... Download it but DONT install it... Go to /Library/Updates and in there is where the update pkg file lives... Copy (don't delete it or cut it) out of there and install manually. Watch the logs.. i.e. note before and after times!

If it asks you to reboot.. Don't... So ti'll probably try and install.. But get the package anyway...

Install that manually...

In steps:

1. Download and install the update
2. After installation, don't restart
3. Drop to terminal or use finder and goto (cmd+shift+g) /Library/Updates
4. Copy the OS X update to somewhere else i.e. on your desktop
5. Restart and see if the update worked
6. If it worked... Stop here :D
7. If not... Fire up "Console" in Utilities under your applications....
8. Note the time of the logs under "All Messages"
9. Install the update by double clicking on it and install it as you would any other pkg file
10. After the install, reboot.
11. Go back to console.. Note the end time!!!!
12. If it worked! Stop here :D
13. If it didn't work, can you go through the logs and see if anything fails or complains and come back with that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not on the store anymore.
Try to find the installer somewhere else.
For example:
http://download.cnet.com/Apple-Mac-OS-X-Mavericks/3000-18513_4-76018588.html